# Getting error while running Yii2 project on windows 8.1

Tags: php, xampp, yii2

I have successfully installed Yii2 using composer on windows 8.1. I am using Xampp server but I am not able to run my project successfully.

I am getting this error:

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\application\web/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\web\index.php on line 7

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\application\web/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\web\index.php on line 7
```

I have also given proper permissions and set the cookie validation key but nothing is working.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Where is your autoload.php located?

Comment: I got the solution. I need to install the vendor package and now the application is running fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is self explainable. There is no `autoload.php` file in `vendor` folder. It's generated after all `vendor` packages will be installed.

Use `composer install` command to install all packages.